# Converting a List<String> to a List<Integer> (or any class that extends Number)

Tags: java, generics, collections, guava

I want to create a very generic utility method to take any Collection and convert it into a Collection of a user selectable class that extends from Number (Long, Double, Float, Integer, etc.)

I came up with this code that uses Google Collections to transform the Collection and to return an Immutable List.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
/**
     * Takes a {@code List<String>} and transforms it into a list of the
     * specified {@code clazz}.
     * 
     * @param <T>
     * @param stringValues
     *            the list of Strings to be used to create the list of the
     *            specified type
     * @param clazz
     *            must be a subclass of Number. Defines the type of the new List
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Number> List<T> toNumberList(List<String> stringValues, final Class<T> clazz) {
        List<T> ids = Lists.transform(stringValues, new Function<String, T>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public T apply(String from) {
                T retVal = null;
                if (clazz.equals(Integer.class)) {
                    retVal = (T) Integer.valueOf(from);
                } else if (clazz.equals(Long.class)) {
                    retVal = (T) Long.valueOf(from);
                } else if (clazz.equals(Float.class)) {
                    retVal = (T) Float.valueOf(from);
                } else if (clazz.equals(Double.class)) {
                    retVal = (T) Double.valueOf(from);
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Type %s is not supported (yet)", clazz.getName()));
                }
                return retVal;
            }
        });
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(ids);
    }
```

It can be used like this:

```
// Convert List<String> to List<Long>
List<Long> ids = MiscUtils.toNumberList(productIds, Long.class);
```

Is my code overkill or how would you simplify it and at the same time keep it generic enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the most important aspect of this code is the `Function` as opposed to the method itself. I also don't think it makes sense to switch over the subclasses you allow in the `Function` body, as you already know what type of `Number` you want to return at the time the `Function` is created. It's also slightly problematic that your method fails if given, say, `BigInteger.class`.

Given this, what I would do is create a utility class (let's call it `Numbers`) and provide methods on it that each return a `Function` (which can be an `enum` singleton) for parsing a `String` as a specific type of `Number`. That is:

```
public class Numbers {
  public static Function<String, Integer> parseIntegerFunction() { ... }
  public static Function<String, Long> parseLongFunction() { ... }
  ...
}
```

They could each be implemented something like this:

```
public static Function<String, Integer> parseIntegerFunction() {
  return ParseIntegerFunction.INSTANCE;
}

private enum ParseIntegerFunction implements Function<String, Integer> {
  INSTANCE;

  public Integer apply(String input) {
    return Integer.valueOf(input);
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return "ParseIntegerFunction";
  }
}
```

This can then be used however users want:

```
List<String> strings = ...
List<Integer> integers = Lists.transform(strings, Numbers.parseIntegerFunction());
```

This approach has quite a few advantages over yours:

- Doesn't require any switching in the `Function`... we know what type of number we're creating and just do that. Faster.
- Is more flexible, in that each `Function` can be used wherever... users aren't forced to use it the way your method does (copying the transformed values into an `ImmutableList`.
- You only create the `Function`s you actually want to allow. If there's no `BigInteger` parsing function, users just can't call that, as opposed to having it be completely legal to do that at compile time and then fail at runtime like in your example.

As a side note, I'd recommend making the return type of any method that returns an `ImmutableList` be `ImmutableList` rather than `List`... it provides information that is useful to clients of the method.

**Edit:**

If you *really need* something more dynamic (i.e. you want classes that have an instance of some `Class<T extends Number>` to be able to transform `String`s to that `Number` type) you could also add a lookup method like:

```
public static <T extends Number> Function<String, T> parseFunctionFor(Class<T> type) {
  // lookup the function for the type in an ImmutableMap and return it
}
```

This has the same problems as your original method, though, if there's a `Number` subclass that you don't provide a `Function` for. It also doesn't seem like there would be many situations where this would be useful.

Comment: @ColinD: But if your client didn't *know* which type of Number they wanted, they could use these methods (as long as they in turn had a class token).  I like this approach but it doesn't seem to address the same situations as the question did.

Comment: I do agree in general though that this simply isn't a great application of generics, since each type must be treated separately anyhow.

Comment: @Mark: I was under the impression that the general idea was to use this by passing a class literal for a specific number type directly to it, as opposed to anything more dynamic. However, it's easy enough to create a method that is given a `Class<T extends Number>` and returns the correct `Function` based on that.

Comment: @ColinD: which I prefer to the OP's code.  A little Map does nicely to get rid of the ugly ifs.

Comment: I'm going to go with this approach. I'm wondering why is there no method like this in Google Collections already.

Comment: @Eliseo: I imagine it wasn't considered generally useful enough to add (yet anyway) or some such. There are lots of number and math related `Function`/`Predicate` operations one might want to do, and trying to add those would increase the size of the API (making it harder to learn). Guava operates under the "when in doubt, leave it out" principle. Plus, in Java 8 you'll be able to use a method reference like `Integer#valueOf(String)` as a `Function` and have no need for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you implement several transformer functions and pass them to Lists.transform() call?

```
    public class IntegerTransformer extends Function<String, Integer>() {
        public Integer apply(String from) {
            return Integer.valueOf(from);
        }
    }
```

So, you could write:

```
Lists.transform(stringValues, new IntegerTransformer());
```

If you want to handle types automatically, you can add a transformer factory or a map:

```
static Map<Class,Function<String,?>> transformers = new HashMap<String,?>();
static {
  transformers.put(Integer.class, new IntegerTransformer());
  transformers.put(Integer.class, new LongTransformer());
  ...
}

public static Function<String,?> get(Class c) {
  Function<String,?> transformer = transformers.get(c);
  if(transformer==null) {
    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Type %s is not supported (yet)", clazz.getName()));
  }
  return transformer;         
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend exposing these functions as types like `IntegerTransformer`. There's no need for the client to know the implementation type, just that there's a `Function<String, Integer>` that does what they want. There's also no need for clients to ever instantiate these themselves, since they're stateless and can be singletons.

Comment: Sure. The main idea is to remove all repeated logic out of the transformer functions. The rest is the implementation details. E.g. I wouldn't recommend to use enums to create singletons, besides forcing singletons is an overkill in this case.

Comment: @Eugene Kuleshov: Why wouldn't you recommend it? It's pretty much unequivocally the best way to make a singleton. And I don't think there's any reason not to make them singletons, particularly if you're going to be storing an instance of each in a `Map` anyway.

Comment: @Eugene: Basically everything you just said is wrong. I recommend reading _Effective Java_ as well as not making statements you can't back up.

Comment: @ColinD Are you suggesting enums were created to make singletons? Josh Bloch's book is a good reading, yet it reflects the author's opinion on certain points of the language, so I'd still take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Eugene: I'm not suggesting they were created to make singletons, just that Bloch is correct that they happen to be perfect for making them. Think about it: an enum with a single element is a canonical singleton--it's a class that guarantees that there will be 1 and only 1 instance of itself. It also provides serializability and the guarantee of singleton-ness through serialization and deserialization for you. I'd hardly call it an "opinion" that enums are the best way to implement a singleton given the real, concrete advantages of the approach.

Comment: @ColinD: I would say that it is convenient way to implement singleton, but it doesn't make it the best one. Besides, I believe it is still possible to create multiple instances trough different classloaders.

Comment: @Eugene: You keep saying it might not be the best or that what Josh Bloch says is an "opinion" and can be taken with a grain of salt, but you have provided _no_ arguments against it that are based on facts where Josh Bloch provides a whole section on why it's a good idea. Until you come up with some convincing reasons that some other method is better, I'm gonna say that the method of doing it that's generally agreed to be the best by Java experts is probably the best.

Comment: @ColinD we both agreed that we have different opinions on that. I believe that using enum is semantically misleading and gives potentially false feeling of safe singletons. Unfortunately there is no ideal way to deal with this in Java, but other languages have language-level constructs for singleton objects.

Comment: @Eugene: The thing here is that the enum singleton is being used purely as an _internal_ detail. Clients of the `parseIntegerFunction()` method don't even need to know that it's a singleton and likely should never need to look at the code for it. And if by "safe singletons" you mean "singletons that can share a single instance across classloader boundaries", I think that's a non-issue since not even `Class` objects are the same across classloader boundaries, much less any other type of singleton construct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.

Since you have the Class token, why not avoid the unchecked cast and thus suppress warnings?

```
retVal = clazz.cast(Double.valueOf(from));
```

Comment: Class.cast() method call is much much slower then a regular cast. So, it is better not to use, unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @Eugene: data/references to complement your downvote please.  It would have to be a non-trivial performance hit for me to not go that route, since it guarantees type safety without requiring inspection.  Typesafety is much more important to me than microoptimizations. I would doubt the cast would result in a shred of performance difference in practice, unless the bulk of an application's logic is transforming lists.

Comment: @Mark simply because it is a method call vs. INSTANCEOF bytecode. The latter is very efficiently folded by HotSpot (i.e. execution path prediction). You can write a simple micro benchmark to verify.

Comment: @Eugene: Actually you can, since you're the one that downvoted me.  I don't think you really know what you're talking about, hence I don't understand the d/v.  For instance, the cast `(T)` won't even **be** in the bytecode since it's unchecked (hence erased at runtime) and yet you say it will be.  Either way, you're concerned about microoptimizations when functional correctness and type safety is much more important here.  If you think performance tuning is more important fine, but it's not worthy of a downvote.  Not like I said something **wrong**.

Comment: @Mark you didn't said anything wrong, it is just you made a bad suggestion for this particular case. The code is invoked for each element from the source collection, so you really need to remove all potential overhead. It is not about micro optimizations, it is about programming style.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't believe me, you can read on what Hotspot can and what it can't optimize at http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Home

Comment: @Eugene: I just did a benchmark and noticed absolutely no performance hit.  If anything my way was consistently faster.  Oh and just throwing me to the homepage of everything hotspot is not providing a reference.  Do some research and then post your findings.

Comment: @Eugene: and yes it is about programming style.  And since there is absolutely **NO EVIDENCE** that there's a performance hit, and even if there WAS a performance hit it would be negligable, my way is better since it's type safe (or rather type safer, in that it fails in the library code where the mistake was made)

Comment: @Mark you need to fix your benchmark. The Hotspot wiki has a good reference on that. In my tests the hit is significant. On 10,000,000 calls of transformer Function on my machine running Java 1.6 the slow down with your "improvement" is about 40..50%. If you would like to see the code, please submit a separate question, I'd be happy to answer you with the complete benchmark code up there.

Comment: @Eugene: So your transformer function, which is ~2% of the work of the entire list copy, which is maybe 0.01% of the work the application needs to do, might be 40% faster.  You're saying that's worth sacrificing type safety?  I mean, we could save maybe 90% of the time of every array access by eliminating bounds checking.  Should we eliminate bounds checking?  Java was made to be SAFE, and you're blatently saying safety isn't as important as shaving off 0.0001% off the runtime of your application.  If that's what you care about, go downvote some assembly answer.  Java is not for you.

Comment: @Mark, you are forgetting that transformer function is called for every element, so it can easily became a bottle neck. Things like that are adding up bit by bit. My solution is compile-time type-safe and it is faster. So, I don't see what are you arguing there.

Answer (score -1):

You could use reflection, and do something like this:

```
      Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class);
      T str = (T) m.invoke(null, from);
      return str;
```

Untested and possible slow.

Comment: The real problem is that those classes don't implement an interface with `valueOf(String)`. If they did, you wouldn't need all this nonsense. You could just create an object of type with newInstance, cast to the interface, and call that.

Comment: If it implemented an interface, you would need an *instance* of the object which leads to other performance impacts.  `valueOf` is static as it is now.  Unfortunately there is no way to have an interface that specifies a static method.

Comment: Better to use Number.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz), so no new unnecessary instance is created.

Comment: @Eugene, @Stefan: Actually that's really completely irrelevant if you're not abusing generics.  We already know `T extends Number` from the bounds.

Comment: Oh, righto. I didn't know of that method, Eugene, so thanks for that.