# Java Android Arraylist string to ArrayList custom class

Tags: java, string, arraylist

How can I convert **values** here:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>
```

to :

```
ArrayList<Custom>
```

**EDIT**:

```
public class Custom {


    public Custom Parse(String input) {
        // What should I do here?
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you convert from String to Custom?

Comment: Can you tell me if I can do some parsing in my Custom class?

Comment: refresh  your question, and put clear question

Comment: what about your custom class and your string data ?

Comment: custom class for parsing ...[see here ...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: What is the real content of your `Custom` class, we cannot know for you what is the String representation of a `Custom`, you're the only one who knows that... Your edit is insufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
List<Custom> customList = new ArrayList<Custom>();
for (String value: values) {
   customList.add(new Custom(value));
}
```

Although it would be better just to add a constructor with a `String` argument:

```
class Custom {
   private final String input;

   public Custom(String input) {
      this.input = input;
   }

   // not needed but implemented for completeness    
   public static Custom parse(String input) {
      return new Custom(input);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of `Custom` objects has the same size with `values` list.
With one enhanced for-loop, set the appropriate fields of your objects like this:

```
int i=0;

for(String str:values)
   customList.get(i++).setSomeProperty(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find a solution using Google Collections libraries on this thread [Converting a List<String> to a List<Integer> (or any class that extends Number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108970/converting-a-liststring-to-a-listinteger-or-any-class-that-extends-number)